# Triggering a job through the GitHub API cancels the currently running job

Tags: github-actions, circleci-2.0

We have two jobs in our circleci commit workflow. The first (`build_and_test`) builds our iOS project and runs some of our unit tests. The second (`build_and_snapshot`) builds our iOS project and runs some longer running UI tests. We want `build_and_test` to run on every commit, including commits made on branches, and the longer running `build_and_snapshot` to run only on master.

However we would also like to be able to on command run `build_and_snapshot` on a branch. So we added a GitHub Action so that if you add a the following PR comment: `/snapshot <branch_name>` circleci runs `build_and_snapshot` on the branch `<branch_name>`.

This is our workflow YAML file:

```
name: Comment commands handler
on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  snapshot:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    if: contains(github.event.comment.body, '/snapshot') && github.event.issue.pull_request
    steps:
      - name: Run snapshots job
        shell: bash
        run: BRANCH_NAME=${COMMENT_BODY#* } && curl -u our_circle_ci_api_key -d build_parameters[CIRCLE_JOB]=build_and_snapshot "https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/gh/project/repo/tree/${BRANCH_NAME}"
        env:
          COMMENT_BODY: ${{ github.event.comment.body }}
```

This works, but it cancels `build_and_test` if it’s running. I think that’s because of the circleci setting that cancels redundant builds. Is there any way around this, aside from disabling that setting? Do we need to poll and wait until `build_and_test` is finished?

Answer (score 0):

Either of your suggested approaches will work - although you may get a race condition if you are polling from GitHub Actions, because many will be running at the same time, and it is likely that two will trigger a build at the same time when one finishes.

Turning off the redundant build setting on CircleCI seems like the best bet.

Btw, the ability for GitHub Actions to act like this (cancel redundant actions) is a highly requested (missing) feature.